# Issue with Authorization (401) with Bearer JWT token using latest OpenAPI / Swagger UI | Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, configuration, swagger, openapi

I'm upgrading from Swagger 2.9.2 to -> OpenAPI / Springdocs (1.6.9) and it's built-in Swagger UI (version 4.10.3). Using the following code *was* working perfectly fine with Swagger 2, allowing the token to be passed along without any issue:

**OLD SWAGGER 2 CONFIGURATION CLASS:**

```
...
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

@Bean
public Docket docket() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.program.programName"))
            .build()
            .globalRequestParameters(defaultParams());
}

private List<RequestParameter> defaultParams() {
    return Collections.singletonList(
            new RequestParameterBuilder()
                    .name("Authorization")
                    .description("auth token")
                    .in(ParameterType.HEADER)
                    .required(true)
                    .build());
  }
}
```

Here's the new configuration class which I added based on OpenAPI's own documentation, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. I'll also post a screenshot of the exact error I'm seeing when trying to access the /swagger-config json data:

**NEW CONFIGURATION (NOT WORKING):**

```
...    
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.program.programName"})
public class SwaggerConfig {

@Bean
public OpenAPI openAPI() {
    return new OpenAPI()
            .info(new Info()
                    .title("Program API")
                    .description("Application")
                    .version("v0.0.1"))
            .components(new Components()
                    .addSecuritySchemes("bearerAuth",
                            new SecurityScheme()
                                    .type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP)
                                    .scheme("bearer")
                                    .bearerFormat("JWT"))
                    .addHeaders("Authorization",
                            new Header()
                                    .description("auth token")
                                    .required(true)));
  }
}
```

[Image of the 401 error trying to get /swagger-config data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGUHb.png)

As you can see in ^that screenshot, I'm getting this "Failed to load remote configuration." error on the main swagger page. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this because it can't access `/v3/api-docs/swagger-config`. You should configure Spring Security to permit access to `/v3/api-docs/**`.

For Webflux this would be:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(final ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
            .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/actuator/**", "/webjars/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();

        return http.build();
    }
}
```